# HTML BASE doesn't work properly in FF 13 and Chromium 18 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: html, firefox, ubuntu, radix, chromium

I got some simple and valid HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="http://localhost/cow/" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/foo.html">bar</a>
</body>
</html>
```

but the link only points to `http://localhost/foo.html` instead of the full URI (with subdir). In addition something like `<base href='http://127.0.0.1/something/' />` doesn't work but it is done as described here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_base.asp

That shouldn't be, or?
How to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the '/' before `foo.html`

```
<a href="foo.html">bar</a>
```

And of course all the slashes before all the relative paths in this web page